# Shopify 'view collection' button in featured collection

Tags: shopify

I'm theming the basic stuff for a webshop and trying to add a 'view collection'-button to the featured collection on the home page. In the documentation it states that normally I just need to do collection.url and get the url. But it doesn't seem to work. Can someone say what I do wrong?
(https://help.shopify.com/themes/liquid/objects/collection#collection-url)

```html
{% if section.settings.show_view_all %}
    <hr class="hr--clear">
    <div class="text-center">
      <a href="{{ section.settings.featured_collection.url }}" class="btn">
        {{ 'collections.general.view_all' | t }}
      </a>
    </div>
{% endif %}
  
  
</div>

{% schema %}
  {
    "name": "Featured collection",
    "class": "index-section",
    "settings": [
      {
        "type": "text",
        "id": "title",
        "label": "Heading",
        "default": "Featured collection"
      },
      {
        "type": "collection",
        "id": "featured_collection",
        "label": "Collection"
      },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check the **collection** setting type:
https://help.shopify.com/themes/development/theme-editor/settings-schema#collection:

> The output of the option the merchant selects from the drop-down is the handle of the collection.

So, instead of:

`{{ section.settings.featured_collection.url }}`

you should use:
`{{ collections[section.settings.featured_collection].url }}`

Answer (score 1):

I wrapped the h2 tag like this:

```
{% if section.settings.title != blank %}
  <a href="/collections/{{ section.settings.home_page_featured_products }}"><h2 class="small--text-center">{{ section.settings.title | escape }}</h2></a>
{% endif %}
```

As I do not ever plan to make the collection slug different, this works for me. Your mileage may vary. This is using the 'Simple' theme.